# Improving my Java object-oriented? Review!

Tags: java, object-oriented

***Did I improve since [then](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28060/is-there-any-way-to-improve-my-java-anything-wrong-with-it)?***

I have been writing this program today, and tried my best to improve my object-oriented understanding.

Mains.java:

```
import games.GameHandler;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

    public class Mains {

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            //Start the game
            startGame();

        }

        private static void startGame() {

            //Declares
            GameHandler handler = new GameHandler();
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);   
            boolean game = true;
            String input = "";  

            //Print program welcome text
            handler.printStart();

            //While in game...
            while (game) {
                //Getting input ready for new commands from the player
                input = console.nextLine();

                //Checking if input was set.
                if (input != null) {
                    //Selecting the game you want to play.
                    handler.selectGame(input);

                    //If game was selected.. then.. let's start playing.
                    while (handler.inGame) {
                        //Use will say something.
                        input = console.nextLine();

                        //If it was "exit", it will go back and select another game.
                        if (input.equals("exit")) {
                            handler.exitGame();
                        } else {
                            //Play again.
                            handler.continueGame(input);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

GameHandler.java:

```
package games;
import java.io.*;

    public class GameHandler {

        private String[] games = {"Spin", "Tof"};
        private String[] navigation = {"Back", "Start"};
        private Spin spin = new Spin();
        private boolean spinGame = false;
        private boolean tofGame = false;
        public boolean inGame = false;

        /**
        * Method printStart
        *
        * Will welcome the player to the program.
        */
        public void printStart() {

            this.print(0, "Welcome to the program!");
            this.print(0, "Please select a game: " + this.availableGames());

        }

        /**
        * Method available games
        *
        * This will print all the games that are located in the games array in one row.
        **/

        private String availableGames() {
            String names = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
                names = (names + games[i]);
                if (i < games.length -1) {
                    names = (names + ", ");
                }
            }

            return names;
        }

        /**
        * Method selectGame
        *
        * This will select the given game.
        * @param command The entered command.
        **/

        public void selectGame(String command) {
            if (this.inArray(command))
            {
                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("spin")) {
                    this.startGame("spin");
                } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("tof")) {
                    this.startGame("tof");
                }
            } else {
                this.print(0, "Could not find game!");
            }
        }

        /**
        * Method inArray
        *
        * This will check if the entered game name is exisiting in the games array.
        * If yes, will return a boolean true, else false.
        *
        * @param value The entered game name.
        * @return boolean true/false.
        **/

        private boolean inArray(String value) {
            int returning = 0;
            for (String s : games) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    returning = 1;
                }
            }
            if (returning == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Method startGame
        *
        * Will start the game, and print instructions.
        * will set the game boolean to true.
        **/

        private void startGame(String game) {
            switch (game) {
                case "spin":
                    this.print(0, "Welcome to spin game!");
                    this.print(0, "Please click on any key to spin!");
                    spinGame = true;
                break;
                case "tof":
                break;
            }

            inGame = true;
        }

        /**
        * Method continueGame
        *
        * Will continue the game, either spin again, or print new question or even answer.
        * @param command The entered command.
        **/
        public void continueGame(String command) {
            while (inGame) {
                if (spinGame) {
                    this.spinWheel();
                    // Break out of the loop.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
        * Method exitGame
        *
        * Exit the game..
        **/

        public void exitGame() {
            spinGame = false;
            tofGame = false;
            this.printStart();
        }

        /**
        * Method spinWheel
        *
        * This will spin the wheel.
        **/

        private void spinWheel() {
            this.print(0, spin.spinWheel());
        }

        /**
        * Method print
        *
        * Prints text using System.out
        * @param type printing type (Println/print).
        * @param message The message
        **/

        private void print(int type, String message) {
            switch (type) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(message);
                break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.print(message);
                break;              
            }
        }
    }
```

spin.java:

```
package games;
import java.util.Random;

    public class Spin {

        /**
        * The base auth we are going to work with..
        **/

        private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5; 

        /**
        * Creating new Random object.
        **/

        private Random r = new Random();

        /**
        * Method spinWheel
        *
        * Spins the damn wheel..
        * @return spinned value + if you won or not.
        **/

        public String spinWheel() {
            return this.spinWheel(this.rand(100));
        }

        /**
        * spinWheel
        *
        * Returning results.
        **/

        private String spinWheel(int number) {

            int result = this.Calculate(this.rand(number));

            if (result < 101) {
                return "You have won the game!" + result;
            } else {
                return "You've lost the game!" + result;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Method calculate
        *
        * Calculates the spin.
        * @return the spinned number.
        **/


        private int Calculate(int Number) {

            int var = this.rand(101);

            int holder = (var * Number) / 2;

            return holder + this.auth;
        }

        /**
        * Shortcut for nextInt of Random
        **/

        public int rand(int x) {
            return r.nextInt(x);
        }

    }
```

What's wrong with it? did I improve since last time? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use a meaningful title and tell us what your code does and what it is supposed to do (and if you have any doubts about it).

Answer (score 4):

i would suggest to change

```
  private boolean inArray(String value) {
        int returning = 0;
        for (String s : games) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                returning = 1;
            }
        }
        if (returning == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

to

```
  private boolean inArray(String value) {
        boolean doesExist = false;
        for (String s : games) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                doesExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return doesExist;
    }
```

To OP : Pretty impressive improvement since then.

Put this

```
public class GameHandler {

    private String[] games = {"Spin", "Tof"};
    private String[] navigation = {"Back", "Start"};
    private Spin spin = new Spin();
    private boolean spinGame = false;
    private boolean tofGame = false;
    public boolean inGame = false;
```

into the `GameHandler` constructor, it is a convention to define non-static variable in the class **constructor**.

---

You have a massive error in your `Spin` class. you have declared `private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;`. So do you know how [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword works? i don't think so, after running your new code and judge it by the previous i think that you only try break your huge code into smaller part without thinking the logic how it will be executed. I will recommend you to at first do some basic Java programming with small classes and methods and you should start with the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html). Good Luck.

Comment: Once doesExist is true why not just exist immediately rather than continue the loop?

Comment: Instead of returning `doesExist`, you can just do `for (String s : games) { if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) { return true; } } return false;` There's no need for the variable.

Comment: @Corbin i was trying to change the code as close as OP's code.

Comment: @tintinmj Sometimes code should be drastically different than the OPs :).

Answer (score 2):

Building on tintinmj’s answer, I would change his suggestion of

```
private boolean inArray(String value) {
    boolean doesExist = false;
    for (String s : games) {
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            doesExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return doesExist;
}
```

into

```
private boolean inArray(String value) {
    for (String s : games)
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

– Another reduction by half.